# Check if Random Exist in the database before inserting

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

i made a small code that generates different type of code, but i'll make it simpler,

i have a registration form submitted while submitting i collect some info about the user and i create for him a random, but i want this random to be unique for this user.

so i have 3 cases :

```
$code_random = rand(1000,9999);
    if($code_random < 0){
    $code_random = -$code_random;
    }

$random = $fname.$code_random; //case 1
$random = $lname.$code_random; //case 2
$random = $fname.lname.$code_random; //case 3
```

But i want to create case 1 check if this random exist in the database, if it does use the second case if it does use the third case, before submitting the form and without displaying anything for the user.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel - SQL databases have two great ways of assigning unique IDs to every row.

1) Auto-incrementing primary key - goes up by one for every new row. Managed by the database, guaranteed to not use the same value for two rows by mistake. Nice and small and simple. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

2) GUIDs (also known as UUIDs) - The algorithm used to generate GUIDs means that you'll never see the same one twice, ever. Over auto-incrementing integers, they have the advantage of being unpredictable, being generateable outside of the database and being meaningful outside of their database table context. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a random integer, you can use the [`MySQL - rand()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function for this

```
insert into users (id, ...) values (FLOOR(1000 + RAND() * (9999 – 1000)), ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of making infos unique: Create a unique index on the database column.

Then simply insert what you want and check if the database complains about violating the unique index. If this is the case, use one of your alternative queries and check again.

What if the last query still does not work?